# Call function on each array element

Tags: javascript, foreach, compiler-errors

I'm trying to pass every element of an array to my function:

```
e.target.files.forEach(myfunction);
```

But I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'forEach'

I did a console log on it and confirmed the array is not empty.

Comment: Whatever `e.target.files` is, it doesn't have a `forEach()` method.

Comment: Try `[].forEach.call(e.target.files, function(){})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.target.files` is probably not a real `Array` so it doesn't have a `forEach()` method.  I'm guessing it is a [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object.

You may have to iterate it yourself or apply array methods to it indirectly.

```
var files = e.target.files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    myfunction(files[i]);
}
```

FYI, it is common for the DOM to use pseudo Array types of data structures that have a `.length` property and can be indexed with `[index]`, but are not actual `Array` objects so they don't have all the other array methods.  [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) is another such Array-like object used by the DOM that isn't an actual array.

It is also possible to copy this psuedo-array into an actual array or apply some array methods to it using `.call()` or `.apply()`, but I don't see that as necessary here.  I'd for for the simple `for` loop above as it's nice and clear what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

Foreach is not a default method to array. If you copied this code, verify which file is beeing added.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: `forEach` is a standard method on `Array` since ECMAScript 5.